# Haskell High Order Functions

Tags: haskell

I'm a little bit confuse about high order function and I wanted to do a stupid example to see if I understood well but still I can't compile without errors, i.e I guess I'm missing something. My very basic example is as follow, I create a function that adds up two number, and then I create an other function which uses my previous function and sum up an other number.

```
Sum2 :: Double -> Double -> Double  
Sum2  a b = a + b

Sum3 :: (Double -> Double -> Double) -> Double -> Double    
Sum3 a b c = (Sum2 a b) + c


test1:: Double
test1 = Sum3 2.0 3.0 4.0
```

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: Your example is just a function calling another function. That's not higher order, which would require taking a function as an argument or returning a function from a function.

Comment: Ok, may be I'm confused, I thought that I was doing higher order by calling sum2 in the argument of sum3. It's my first day in Haskell and I am clearing mixing up some concepts. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no question, but I'll guess the OP wants some explanation about why this is not working:

```
Sum3 :: (Double -> Double -> Double) -> Double -> Double    
Sum3 a b c = (Sum2 a b) + c
```

First, functions should have a lowercase name. Second, the type above is the type of a function with two arguments:

```
sum3 :: (Double -> Double -> Double) -> Double -> Double    
        ----- first arg ------------    -2nd--    -result type-
```

So, one should write

```
sum3 f a = ...
```

where `f` is the function passed as first argument `Double -> Double -> Double`, and `a` is the second argument number. Since `f` is a function taking two arguments, we need to use it accordingly, e.g.

```
sum3 f a = f a a
-- or
sum3 f a = f a 12
-- or
sum3 f a = f (a+12) (f 32 a)
```

I have no idea about what you are trying to achieve, the above ones are only examples.

Finally, the name `sum3` is unintuitive, we should use something else.

Comment: Thank you Chi, may be I'm confused about how to call declare and call functions but you example helped me. Have a nice day :)